# Gerbes and Brauer group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory, sheaf-cohomology, higher-category-theory

Let $µ$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on a site $C$. There is a bijection
between isomorphism (equivalence) classes of µ-gerbes over $C$ and $H^2
(C, µ)$.

Can someone give me a good reference for the proof of this statement (at least in the case of a site with a terminal object)?

Thanks!

Comment: This is proved in Corollary 7.2.2.27 of Lurie's Higher Topos Theory.